# Pass an exception to the default ASP.Net CORE error handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm using ASP.NET CORE 3.1 project in the new release of VS Community 2019

In the `Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)` in my `startup.cs` file I have the line:

```
app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
```

So when I throw an error somewhere in a `Controller` e.g.

```
throw new Exception("User Not Found!");
```

This then bounces to this default `IActionResult` in the `HomeController`:

```
[ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
public IActionResult Error()
{
    return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
}
```

I was hoping to pass something (either the `Exception` or its message) to the `IActionResult Error()` but I'm not sure that's possible.

So then I thought

**is the `Exception` thrown in the `BaseController` accessible from the `Error IActionResult` at all? Possibly by using the `HttpContext` or the `Activity` ?**

I can't seem to find anything using the intellisense, not sure I'm approaching it the right way and probably need to setup a whole new error handling system.

Comment: You can use action filters. For more details refer to this [Error Handling](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/oct/16/error-handling-and-exceptionfilter-dependency-injection-for-aspnet-core-apis)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should add ErrorHandlingMiddleware

```
app.UseMiddleware<ErrorHandlingMiddleware>();

public class ErrorHandlingMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate next;

    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    public ErrorHandlingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        this.next = next; 
        _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<ErrorHandlingMiddleware>();
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context /* other dependencies */)
    {
        try
        {
            await next(context);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await HandleExceptionAsync(context, ex);
        }
    }

    private static Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception ex)
    {
        var code = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError; // 500 if unexpected

        if (ex is AuthenticationException)
        {
            code = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
        }
        var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
        {
            Status = "Error",
            ErrorCode = (int)code,
            ErrorMessage = ex.Message,
        });
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)code;
        return context.Response.WriteAsync(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, I had no idea Middleware was so easy to implement. When I search handling errors in asp.net core it seems there are some very convoluted ways to do things. This is great. Direct and easy to swallow.